# Python symbolic

Tags: python

How can I create vector with symbolic e1,e2,e3..

[e1;e2;e3]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python equation solve...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924301/python-equation-solve)

Comment: @thaking: Perhaps look at SymPy: http://code.google.com/p/sympy/

Comment: This question should have not been closed, symbols are a well-known construct in programming, used in 99% of programming languages to represent variables. This person is asking if python has a Symbol class or reifies access to them in some way. Next time, rather than voting to close, perhaps say "what do you mean by 'symbolic'?" before you do, if you are unfamiliar with the concept.

Comment: @thaking I voted to close the question because it was a duplicate. You should have edited your initial question. Because you have now deleted that question, I guess I'll vote to reopen this one.

Comment: Put more effort into explaining your questions and maybe they won't get closed.

Comment: I voted to close it because, even if you know what a symbol is, and I do, it is still a long way from the poster's word salad to "does Python have a Symbol class or reify access to symbols in some way?" If the poster is looking for a feature he is used to in MATLAB, perhaps he might mention that in the question somewhere, and explain that feature in more detail so that people who aren't familiar with MATLAB might recognize it.